# Not able to include XML namespaces in PowerShell v4

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Written a code that contains the namespace `using namespace system.xml.linq` in my Powershell script, but I get an error like

```
At line:1 char:1
+ using namespace system.xml.linq
+ ~~~~~
The 'using' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
```

What is wrong with the namespace? Im using PowerShell ver 4.0.

I tried including other `using System;
using System.Xml;` namespaces, but have not got any fruitful information.

```
using namespace system.xml.linq
```

What is wrong with the namespace?

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

Comment: @MaheshMohan f6a4 gave you that hint, not me.

Comment: Ahw.. Thank you @f6a4..

Comment: As far as I know this feature was introduced in Powershell 5 - that's why you are getting syntax error while using Powershell 4.